# How to run Java program through the terminal in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I know how to run and compile a basic Java program in the terminal using `java` and `javac`.

I also know how to run and compile a Java program using IntelliJ.

However, how do you run a program in an IntelliJ project using the terminal.

So far all my classes is compiled to a "out/production/myproject" folder by default in Intellij. So far I have tried the following command in the above folder:

```
java Main
```

However for some reason it says:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run a program in Intellij, in the run window (bottom panel) the very first line is what intellij terminal command. The line usually is shortened like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java...
```

If you click on it, it will show you full command that Intellij runs.

Comment: I looked at it, but it looks ridiculously long, many of which can be shorted considerably. Like the first statement can be reduced to just java and I think many of it is redundant. Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify the classpath before calling `java Main`.